# How to call JAWT_FreeDrawingSurface from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have an application using Swing and LWJGL running nice and stable using a dedicated rendering thread. I have made sure all OpenGL and JAWT calls are made on my rendering thread and not on EDT (this includes `JAWT_GetDrawingSurface`, `JAWT_DrawingSurface_Lock`, `JAWT_DrawingSurface_Unlock`).

My threads are Java threads, `JAWT_xxxx` functions are called from the `org.lwjgl.opengl.awt` toolkit, I have currently no native code of my own.

There is one call left which is done from the AWT thread when the UI components arfe disposed: `JAWT_FreeDrawingSurface` called from `org.lwjgl.opengl.awt.PlatformWin32GLCanvas#dispose`. One solution would be to create a customized version of all `org.lwjgl.opengl.awt` classes and prevent this call being made (and call it from my thread instead). While this is possible, before I do so, I would like to check if there is perhaps another solution?

The documentation for [The Java AWT Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/AWT_Native_Interface.html) quotes the source comments - `struct jawt_DrawingSurface`):

First:

```
/*
 * JAWT_DrawingSurface
 * Structure for containing the underlying drawing information of a component.
 * All operations on a JAWT_DrawingSurface MUST be performed from the same
 * thread as the call to GetDrawingSurface.
 */
```

and later:

```
    /* Cached reference to the Java environment of the calling thread.
     * If Lock(), Unlock(), GetDrawingSurfaceInfo() or
     * FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo() are called from a different thread,
     * this data member should be set before calling those functions.
     */
     JNIEnv* env;
```

I read the second paragraph as "it is possible to call the functions from a different thread, but a special care needs to be taken". What is not clear to me is: how do I set this data member before calling those functions? Is this something that can be done from Java, or do I need a native code for that?

Comment: Yes, you need to do this in native code. It would look something like `surface->env = env;`

Comment: I was afraid I will hear that. I see now my question was not detailed enough, I have added some more detail - I am currently doing everything from Java. Does that mean that to call `JAWT_DrawingSurface` from different Java threads I would have to create some customized version of `JAWT` which would set the `env` from the native code?

Comment: I gave the LWJGL codebase a quick look and got lost in the different levels of code generation involved. You should figure out how `getDrawingSurface` sets the `env` in the first place and see if there is an accessor you can use.